# Why doesn't my model produce accurate training results from the MNIST database?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, mnist

I am relatively new to neural networks. I am currently trying to make a model to identify written characters from the MNIST database, however my training accuracy is extremely low. I was wondering, what can I do to improve my results and what was wrong with how I was originally approaching the issue. Thanks!

```
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Activation
from keras.layers.core import Dense
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras.datasets import mnist
import numpy as np

BATCH_SIZE = 20
EPOCHS = 15

#load data. x is images, y is label
(train_x, train_y), (test_x, test_y) = mnist.load_data()

#reshape into 784 1d array rather than 28, 28 2d array
train_x = np.reshape(train_x, (60000, 784))
train_x = train_x.astype('float32')
train_x = train_x / 255.0

test_x = np.reshape(test_x, (10000, 784))
test_x = test_x.astype('float32')
test_x = test_x / 255.0

print("Done!")


model = Sequential([
    Dense(16, input_shape=(784,), activation='relu'),
    Dense(32, activation='relu'),
    Dense(10, activation='softmax')    
])

model.compile(optimizer='SGD', loss='mse', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(train_x, train_y, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, epochs=EPOCHS, shuffle=True, verbose=2, validation_data=(test_x, test_y))

print("Done!")

def visualize_data():
    string = ""
    count = 0
    for x in train_x[2]:
        if ((count % 28) == 0):
            print(string)
            string = ""
        if x < 10:
            string = string + " " + str(x)+ " "
        elif x < 100:
            string = string + " " + str(x)
        elif x < 1000: 
            string = string + str(x)
   
        count += 1
```

Comment: mse is not a loss for classification problem

Comment: https://keras.io/examples/vision/mnist_convnet/